# Problem developing WF4 application - The requested resource has moved to the one of the following locations

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, iis-express

I am developing a WF4 application. The workflows are hosted in an ASP.NET website. For development, I am using IIS express.

When debugging between edit cycles I get this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
  Message=The requested resource has moved to the one of the following locations:
    https://localhost:44305/Workflows/PerformanceAppraisal/Exempt.xamlx
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
       at GoodwillHR.ExemptPAService.ExemptPAClient.ExemptPAClientChannel.EndGetSelfAppraisalForEmployeeUpdate(IAsyncResult result)
       at GoodwillHR.ExemptPAService.ExemptPAClient.GoodwillHR.ExemptPAService.IExemptPA.EndGetSelfAppraisalForEmployeeUpdate(IAsyncResult result)
       at GoodwillHR.ExemptPAService.ExemptPAClient.EndGetSelfAppraisalForEmployeeUpdate(IAsyncResult result)
       at GoodwillHR.ExemptPAService.ExemptPAClient.OnEndGetSelfAppraisalForEmployeeUpdate(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
  InnerException:
```

What is the problem?

Some more info: XAMLX workflow with multiple receives. Content correlation is set up correctly as everything works fine if I don't stop the debugger.

I am getting the error after I stop the debugger, start debugging again and then call one of the workflow receive activities on a persisted workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but doing a service reference update made this problem go away. I didn't think I had any changes in my workflow service.

Comment: No, this was nearly 1 year ago. I can say that we yanked WF out of this application and replaced it with our own workflow engine and EVERYONE is much happier now.

Comment: I am also using WF and my client app is logging this same error. My WF is hosted as individual WCF service. Not sure why getting this error. Also error is random i.e. most of the time this works but sometime it fails. Any idea?